# React Horizontal Scroll Tabs jumping on tap?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component which works perfectly on web browsers on the computer. You click the animal name to show the animal below, or you click and drag to scroll horizontally to show more animals.

When testing this on a touch device, such as an iPhone, you can click the animal names and it works, but once you scroll horizontally with your finger, then you tap to select an animal, it jumps and doesn't select the animal.

The point is for the code to work on both computers as shown above, and touch devices, which is where it breaks.

[Here is the sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-hill-i7ndz4-d52x5?file=/src/App.js)

Any idea how we can fix this?

Comment: Its working fine if 'setTimeout' is removed, is it necessary to use 'setTimeout' here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**ISSUE :** not using `setTimeout` properly

You can generate the issue on web also, you can just **click single** time on any element, it will get selected and it will become draggable, but it should just select. so why this weird behaviour. let's see that

```
// execution flow, when you just single click and don't drag

onMouseDown = e => {
  const tabsH = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs["tabsH"]); // <----------------- 1
  setTimeout(() => { // <----------------- 2
    // here we are adding active class , 
    // that will not be removed, because (no 5) already executed before this
    // which makes your element draggable
    tabsH.classList.add("active"); // <----------------- 7
    this.setState({ // <----------------- 7.1
      isPressedDown: true,
      startX: e.pageX - tabsH.offsetLeft,
      scrollLeft: tabsH.scrollLeft
    });
  }, 100);
};

onMouseUp = () => {
  const tabsH = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs["tabsH"]); // <----------------- 3
  this.setState({ isPressedDown: false }); // <----------------- 4
  tabsH.classList.remove("active"); // <----------------- 5
  setTimeout(() => { // <----------------- 6
    this.setState({ isScrolling: false }); // <----------------- 8
  }, 500);
};
```

---

**SOLUTION :**

**1)** Put the no 4 and 5 inside the `setTimeout`

**2)** Make sure that `setTimeout` time inside the `onMouseUp` should be greater than the `onMouseDown` `setTimeout`'s time ( to solve the single click issue )

```
onMouseDown = e => {
  const tabsH = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs["tabsH"]);
  setTimeout(() => {
    tabsH.classList.add("active");
    this.setState({
      isPressedDown: true,
      startX: e.pageX - tabsH.offsetLeft,
      scrollLeft: tabsH.scrollLeft
    });
  }, 100);
};

onMouseUp = () => {
  const tabsH = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs["tabsH"]);
  setTimeout(() => {
    tabsH.classList.remove("active"); // <---- this should be inside setTimout
    this.setState({ isPressedDown: false }); // <---- this should be inside setTimout
    this.setState({ isScrolling: false });
  }, 200); // <---- just make sure that this is greater than the `onMouseDown` setTimeout
};
```

> **NOTE :** I dont't know what is the use of `setTimeout` here, so I've just keep as it is, but you can remove that also and it will also work

**WORKING DEMO :** (with timeout)

[image: Edit gracious-hill-i7ndz4]

**WORKING DEMO :** (without timeout)

[image: Edit #SO-without-timeout]

Comment: The reason we had the timeout I think was for computers, in my example, when you quick click an animal, it won't show the draggable cursor, if you long click (press the mouse and hold it), then it would show the draggable cursor by adding the active class and allow dragging. I tried in both your examples and even though it scrolls on mobile without jumping which fixes the jumping issue, on computers even a quick click adds the draggable cursor and allows dragging. Any idea how to resolve that and only show the draggable cursor/allow dragging on a long click on computer and keep the mobile fix?

Comment: You can increase the timeout in onMouseUp and check, it will solve the issue I think

Comment: Hmmm... it seems that 500 ms onMouseDown is a good timeout do differentiate between a quick click and a long press to show drag cursor and give drag functionality (which is what I have in the original sandbox), but I've been playing around with it and your sandbox but still can't get it to work correctly.

Comment: I think you should do some styling to show its dragable like show arrow on right , ot just half text so that people know its dragable or set cursor on hover instead of click, in that case there is no need of setTimeout.

Comment: I upvoted your answer but it still doesn't work as expected on computer without the 500ms settimeout, which breaks on mobile, so I can't mark it as answered yet, as it was part of the question to work on both computer and mobile as expected.

Comment: Okay , will you please explain bit in detail ,what's the exact thing that you need so I can solve it.

Comment: please check this url, i've added the timeout based on device, https://codesandbox.io/s/so-with-timeout-vwfgu?file=/src/App.js, you can check that on both desktop and mobile.

Comment: Basically, for it to work on mobile (which it now does without jumping per your timeout fix), but on computer to not have the dragging cursor shown/dragging functionality working unless it is a mouse press and hold of 500ms. 500ms of pressing and holding the mouse tells us that this is a long press, and the user wants to drag, anything less than 500ms should just be the normal behavior where the user is clicking to see the content, but not to drag.

Comment: Will you please check the link, provided in previous comment,I think that will solve your issue for both

Comment: I think your fix works when I added and cleared the setTimeout. Thank you for your help Vivek. SO needs a few more hours to award bounty, will award it as soon as possible.

Comment: Glad to know, I've also find another way, you can reload the same link and check